# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse in android

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

when Run my app it gives 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse

i tried several  times changed min sdk level but still gives the error.
please if anyone ever solved it,please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: This exception indicates that the JVM looked in its internal class definition data structure for the definition of a class and did not find it. This is different than saying that it could not be loaded from the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

1) Download the Parse SDK

2) Extract it someplace (eg. H:/Downloads/Parse/ )

3) Open Android Studio and Open your project

4) Goto File > Project Structure

5) Select Libraries from the Left Pane

6) Press the Plus Button and select Java from the dropdown

7) Navigate to Parse-1.2.5.jar file that you had downloaded and extracted and select it.

8) Add it to your project

9) Press OK

10) Thats it. Now it Should work properly

Comment: I did exactly the same thing but still it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

don't forget this line

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
```

[Parse Quick Start](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing)